# Books of set theory and algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

Someone knows two good books they focus more on exercises:

On following topics:

1) One of set theory and abstract algebra( Groups, ring, modules, ecc..)

2) Another on combinatorics, and discrete math, in general.

Cheap especially...

Comment: For abstract algebra: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101371/a-book-for-abstract-algebra-with-high-school-level/1101384#1101384

Comment: @Jyanluka: Check out "How to Prove It" by D. Velleman (ISBN-10: 0521675995) and "Naive Set Theory" by P. Halmos  (ISBN-10: 1614271313)

Comment: Yes, I have  already,in ebook...thanks anyway!!