# Reference request - introductory, superficial, informal and preferably short book on abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I am currently self-studying abstract algebra with Fraleigh's A First Course in Abstract Algebra, of which I have a very good impression. I have just finished the first chapter, "Groups and Subgroups", but I feel like I would like to first read a faster introduction to the subject, one which covers the standard/general topics of abstract algebra, but in a more concise, superficial, even informal way, preferably without going into theorem-proof-corollary mode, so that then I can return to the more standard textbooks already with a general feel for the subject. Is there such a text? Thank you.

Comment: You could try the infinite napkin https://venhance.github.io/napkin/Napkin.pdf Of course this is quite long but if you find the algebra chapters its informal with great examples

Comment: If your goal is to "get a feel," my favorite book for this---by far---is ***Visual group theory*** by Nathan Carter.

Comment: See [**A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/AConcreteApproachToAbstractAlgebra-W.W.Sawyer) by Walter Warwick Sawyer (1959), which was (first) reprinted by [Dover Publications](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486824616) in 1978. Maybe also the books in my answer to [A book for abstract algebra with high school level](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1101443/13130).